# Correct structure and in sentence?

Tags: questions

Is the grammar and structure in the following line correct (specifically in the marked section)?

> In light of this, **it was very much in the interests of myself, the relevant department heads, and the foreign partners to ensure that** the project be completed far before deadline had arrived."

Comment: Side note: You may want to consider changing "...the project be completed far before deadline had arrived." to "...the project be completed far before the deadline had arrived."

Comment: Is it "myself," the reflexive pronoun, that you're concerned with?

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice I accidentally omitted the word "the" when I typed that here...

Comment: @Zan700 - My thought exactly.

Comment: @Zan700 - yes. There's also something else that seems to be bothering me with the text, but I can't quite figure out what...

Answer (score 2):

"In light of this, it was very much in my own interests, as well as those of the relevant department heads and the foreign partners, to ensure that the project would be completed long before the deadline had arrived."

Comment: ... in my interests and those of the relevant department heads and the foreign partners...

Comment: +1 to Chasly.  But I suggest a simplification:  "In light of this, it was in my own interests, as well as those of the relevant department heads and the foreign partners, to complete the project long before the deadline."

Comment: I also think we can omit the second 'the'.  " as well as those of the relevant department heads and foreign partners"

Comment: @ chasly from UK I was reworking the sentence along your lines "... in my interests and those of the relevant department heads and the foreign partners..." But I still wonder about that reflexive pronoun. ab2 suggests "me" but you wouldn't write "... in the interest of me..." "Myself "is wrong, but could a possessive pronoun work in that position? You could write,  "Traveling is an interest of mine." But not "... in the interest of mine." But: "Traveling is the interest of mine that pleases me most."

Answer (score 0):

Simplify.  "In light of this, it was in everyone's interest that the project be completed long before the deadline."

Comment: That was part of my original change, but not an option - the writer insists that those three - himself, the department heads and the partners - be specified. Probably because it was because it was in their interests but not in the interests of others involved in the project...